# Randomly Getting ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a loop that runs some `ExecuteNonQuery` commands. **Occasionally** it returns the error message:

```
 ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available connection. The connections 
 current state is closed.
```

Here is my code:

```
private void MyTimerEventHandler(object src, ElapsedEventArgs a)
{
    sqlCon = new SqlConnection("server=" + appConfig.sqlServer + ";Trusted_Connection=yes;database=testdb;connection timeout=30;");
    sqlCon.Open();

    foreach (TagManager tm in tagManagerList)
    {
        foreach (Tag tag in tm.getTags())
        {
             SqlCommand insCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tag_values (tag_id, value, time) Values (@tagId, @tagValue, @tagTime);", sqlCon);
             insCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tagId", tag.tagNameId));
             insCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tagValue", tag.value));
             insCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tagTime", tag.time));

             insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

This code executes in the event handler of a `Timer` that runs every 15 seconds. The timer is kept alive by `GC.KeepAlive()` if that makes any difference.

Comment: the code implies that sqlCon is a field of the class. Perhaps with the 30 second timeout, you have a new invocation that starts running when an earlier invocation is finishing, and the old one closes the connection midway through?

Comment: You nailed it. This is firing on a 15 second timer so if the first invocation is still running when the second fires then the first will close the connection on the second invocation at some point causing this issue. This is why you don't share the connection object like this.

Comment: Please use using(var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(...)) { } instead. If exception happens between sqlConn.Open() and sqlConn.Close() the connection won't be closed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new connection object for each timer callback:

```
private void MyTimerEventHandler(object src, ElapsedEventArgs a)
{
       SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection( [...]
```

It is normally a bad idea to reuse a connection. In your case you can run into a race condition if that connection is being used in another thread.
Creating new connections should not affect performance as they are pulled from the Connection pool.

Comment: A new connection object for each insert command? I'm inserting 600 rows every 15 seconds and that number may increase in the future. Is this still a good idea?

Comment: I would disagree with your assertion that creating connections in a loop is a good idea.  My experience is that it's a _horrible_ idea.  But the race condition, I do agree with, especially in light of @Mikeb's comments in the main post.  If Mike is right, pooling is your enemy.

Comment: Yes, database connections are retrieved from the Connection Pool so it will reuse the existing one if available.

Comment: Keep the connection outside the loop, you can reuse it there, it is safe. I meant between functions.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I will give this a shot and see if it takes care of the issue. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you connection still open before execute query

```
   if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sqlCon.Open();
                        insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why would my connection be closed? I need to reliably insert every row of a data while the timed event is running, every time it runs.

Comment: Well maybe  you can add a try cath and take error that rise, maybe a error into insert and you are not manage or other case maybe is connectio timeout ... Now try adding a try cath and test .. And let us know

Answer (score 0):

You do not you prepare the insert statement by using the StringBuilder and pass it as text to SQL Command to send once over the SQL SERVER to insert. In this case for all 600 loops , you will need to connect to DB once . Just a thought

Comment: Building a sql query through stringbuilder sounds like a terrible idea. Are you sure there is no BatchInsert object or anything?